# Problems with Applets that contains Java3d in Mac OS Lion and Snow Leopard

Tags: firefox, safari, applet, osx-lion, java-3d

i am using Mac Lion OS, and when i use applets with java3d components, graphics are not displayed, however after you "travel" with a Terminal Window (for instance) in front of the browser where the applet with java3d is displayed, and use mission the control... u can in fact see the graphics.

(This phenomenon happens with several macs with lion and snow leopard)

For this example i used the following link:
http://www-evasion.imag.fr/~Francois.Faure/enseignement/ressources/java/demo/java3d/Text3D/Text3DLoad_plugin.html

Does anyone know how to fix this?

All the Best

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but my experience.

Recent updates to the JVM on OSX have broken backwards compatibility with older Java3D versions.  The last time I played with this (which was about 9 months ago) we were noticing similar issues, where they simply would not run.

This happened in the [1.6.0.20 release](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/CrossPlatform/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate2LeopardUpdate7RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) of the JVM from Apple.  This broke both Java3D and JOGL rendering pipelines, when they went to the Plugin2 architecture.  Since then, I believe the JOGL team has been working on a fix, but I haven't tested it in a while, so I don't know the current status of this fix is, and whether the fix has been incorporated into Java3D.

I have not tested with more recent versions of the Java 7 JDK, but it might help to narrow down the problem, which may also alleviate the problem (or make it worse)